# DynamoDB Credentials Init

Tags: .net, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, credentials

I'm working on an App using DynamoDB ans facebook Login. So far so good i've only been using my FB account to test my app. When I wanted to test with another one, all my request to dynamoDB are rejected. After triple checking everything, I think that I build my credentials wrong. Here's my code:

```
credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(
             "eu-west-1:MY_ID_POOL", // IDENTITY POOL ID
             Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1 // REGION
       );
client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
credentials.AddLogin("graph.facebook.com", _Token);
```

I have trouble finding what I did wrong considering this code has been working for months with my fb account, but it does not with my test accounts. I've tried elevate my test account to both dev and Admin privilege in Facebook Developers, nothing change. I precise my program crash as soon as I try to send a request to DynamoDB, not throwing any exception I could catch.

Thanks very much for the answers.

EDIT: Managed to finaly catch an exception:

Logins don't match. Please include at least one valid login for this identity or identity pool.

When I try to put-item in DB. My identity Pool authorise Facebook Login and App ID is correct. Roles authorise everything so it should not be a problem. What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix the bug. Looks like the identity pool only allow one user at a time( which is weird, have to dig into that). To fix just clear the ID cache from the credentials when stopping the application and switching to another user with:

```
credentials.ClearIdentityCache();
```